# From SQL Management Studio to RPI MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, raspberry-pi, connection

I'm starting to learn databases and I'm experimenting with hardware. On raspberry pi I have installed MySql. I also have installed phpMyAdmin and I can administrate database through web interface.

Now, I want to connect to that database with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but I don't know how. On raspberry I allowed connection from all IP addresses ( not only 127.0.0.1 which is default ) but I don't know what next to do?
When I try to connect I get this message.
https://image.prntscr.com/image/QCKYcgmeRfeRgqMYP6DcbA.png

This is picture of my connecting data. Is this ok?

[https://image.prntscr.com/image/y6g8C-whR4aUEM0qPtg4lg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWuMX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can solely connect to [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), nothing else. Its name should have been a huge giveaway...

There are dozens of desktop applications that you can use to manage a mysql server, such as mysql workbench, sqlyog, heidisql, etc.